# Log Shipping - 24 hour difference between source and destination system times

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are trying to have log shipping work between two database servers where the destination server has a system time set 24 hours earlier than the source system time.  Is it possible to force the destination machine to restore the data (disregarding the transaction file stamps are 24 hours ahead).

Comment: 24h? Which planet are your servers on?

Comment: great question.  Some sort of "rigged" up operation to account for the gathering of "previous" day sales.  I'm not real sure why we are doing this.

Comment: @user99143: Well, on the up side, a problem like this is a pretty good opportunity to *find out* why y'all are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

How about a snapshot @ 00:00 (or 23:59:59) daily? Then you could compare the days however you want without a mechanism such as log shipping in play. I'm a big fan of Snapshots (just be careful where you put the files on disk if it's a busy DB).

Here's the How to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx